# Use R in order to create a new df from one df and its different column values

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm looking for a method in order to create a new [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) from one with multiple informations

Maybe it's still a simple thing for you to do, but I can't really get the desired result, maybe some [r](/questions/tagged/r) specialists could enlighten me?

Here is the first df:

```
Col1    Col2    Event   Colvalue1   Colvalue2
Group1  Sp1.1   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp1.2   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp2.1   1   0.20    B
Group1  Sp3.1   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp4.2   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp5.1   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp1.3   3   1.40    C
Group1  Sp1.4   3   1.40    C
Group1  Sp6.1   3   1.40    C
Group2  Sp6.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp7.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp9.3   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp8.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp8.2   2   0.40    E
Group2  Sp9.1   2   0.40    E
Group2  Sp9.2   2   0.40    E
Group2  Sp10.1  3   NA      NA
Group2  SP11.2  3   NA      NA
Group2  SP12.1  3   NA      NA
Group3  Sp1.1   1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp2.1   1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp3.1   1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp4.1   2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp4.2   2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp1.2   2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp8.1   2   0.3     G
```

the idea is to get a `new_df` output :

```
Species Group1  Group2 Group3
Sp1 A   NA G
Sp2 B   NA NO
Sp3 B   NA NO
Sp4 B   NA G
Sp5 B   NA NA
Sp6 C   D NA
Sp7 NA  D NA
Sp8 NA  E G
Sp9 NA  E NA
Sp10 NA X NA
Sp11 NA X NA
Sp12 NA X NA
```

Here is the explanation: The idea is to first go through each group within the `df1`. Let's take the first one :

```
Col1    Col2    Event   Colvalue1   Colvalue2
Group1  Sp1.1   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp1.2   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp2.1   1   0.20    B
Group1  Sp3.1   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp4.2   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp5.1   2   0.12    B
Group1  Sp1.3   3   1.40    C
Group1  Sp1.4   3   1.40    C
Group1  Sp6.1   3   1.40    C
```

from this group I want to create a `new_df` with the colname `Group1` and in rowname all the `Spname` present in all `df1`:

```
Species Group1
Sp1 
Sp2 
Sp3 
Sp4 
Sp5 
Sp6 
Sp7 
Sp8 
Sp9 
Sp10
Sp11
Sp12
```

**How to fill this table? ** In order to decide what to put for `Sp1` in `Group1`, I look at where this species is present in `Group1:`

```
Col1    Col2    Event   Colvalue1   Colvalue2
Group1  Sp1.1   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp1.2   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp1.3   3   1.40    C
Group1  Sp1.4   3   1.40    C
```

I look at the Colvalue1 column and keep only the Event with the lowest value, here `Event=1` since `Colvalue1=0.20` versus `Colvalue1=1.40` for `Event3`.
That's all I have left:

```
Col1    Col2    Event   Colvalue1   Colvalue2
Group1  Sp1.1   1   0.20    A
Group1  Sp1.2   1   0.20    A
```

That's how I know I'm going to add the letter in the `Colvalue2` column here '`C`':

```
Species Group1
Sp1 A
Sp2 
Sp3 
Sp4 
Sp5 
Sp6 
Sp7 
Sp8 
Sp9 
Sp10
Sp11
Sp12
```

and so on and so forth...

another example for `Sp2` in `Group1`:

Here it is present only once:

```
Group1 Sp2.1 1 0.20 B
```

so I fill in the letter `B`:

```
Species Group1
Sp1 A
Sp2 B
Sp3 
Sp4 
Sp5 
Sp6 
Sp7 
Sp8 
Sp9 
Sp10
Sp11
Sp12
```

and same for `Sp3,4, 5` & `Sp6`:

```
Species Group1
Sp1 A
Sp2 B
Sp3 B
Sp4 B
Sp5 B
Sp6 C
Sp7 
Sp8 
Sp9 
Sp10
Sp11
Sp12
```

on the other hand `Sp7,8` and `9` are not present in this group, so I add a `NA`:

```
Species Group1
Sp1 A
Sp2 B
Sp3 B
Sp4 B
Sp5 B
Sp6 C
Sp7 NA
Sp8 NA
Sp9 NA
Sp10 NA
Sp11 NA
Sp12 NA
```

let's go to the `Group2`... :

```
Col1    Col2    Event   Colvalue1   Colvalue2
Group2  Sp6.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp7.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp9.3   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp8.1   1   1.20    D
Group2  Sp8.2   2   0.40    E
Group2  Sp9.1   2   0.40    E
Group2  Sp9.2   2   0.40    E
```

Here `Sp1,2,3,4` and `5` are not present, so I add `NA` and `Sp6` and `Sp7` are present only in `Event1` so I add the associated letter (`D`):

```
Species Group1 Group2
Sp1 A NA
Sp2 B NA
Sp3 B NA
Sp4 B NA
Sp5 B NA
Sp6 C NA
Sp7 NA D
Sp8 NA
Sp9 NA
Sp10 NA
Sp11 NA
Sp12 NA
```

However, `Sp8` and `Sp9` are both present in `Events 1` and `2`: The Event for which `Sp8` has the `smallest value` in `Colvalue1` is `Event 2` (so it will have the letter `E`). The Event for which `Sp9` has the `smallest value` in `Colvvalue1` is `Event 2` (so it will have the letter `E`).

```
Species Group1 Group2
Sp1 A NA
Sp2 B NA
Sp3 B NA
Sp4 B NA
Sp5 B NA
Sp6 C NA
Sp7 NA D
Sp8 NA E
Sp9 NA E 
Sp10 NA
Sp11 NA
Sp12 NA
```

And then for the `Sp10,11` & `12` in the `Event3` there is not `Colvalue1` so I just put an `X`.

```
Species Group1 Group2
Sp1 A NA
Sp2 B NA
Sp3 B NA
Sp4 B NA
Sp5 B NA
Sp6 C NA
Sp7 NA D
Sp8 NA E
Sp9 NA E 
Sp10 NA X
Sp11 NA X
Sp12 NA X
```

Here's the thing, I hope it's clear enough, feel free to ask questions if any points remain unclear.  If anyone can help me, that would be very nice of him/her. In the meantime, you all take care of yourselves in this complicated time...

Adding complexicity at the `Group3`:

Here when the Colvalue1 is `> to 5` then I a value `NO` if there is no other `Colvalue1 <=` than `5`.

```
Group3  Sp1.1     1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp2.1     1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp3.1     1   5.2     F
Group3  Sp4.1     2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp4.2     2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp1.2     2   0.3     G
Group3  Sp8.1     2   0.3     G
```

so here in the Event 1 for instance the `Sp1` :
    Group3  Sp1.1     1   5.2     F
    Group3  Sp1.2     2   0.3     G

it has a `Colvalue1 > 5` in the `Event1` but it also has a `Colvalue1 = 0.3` in the `Event2` so it takes the value `G`.

But for `Sp2` it is only present into the Event1 with a `Colvalue1 > 5`, so I juste assign a value `NO`.

Here is the dataframe :

> dput(head(df))

```
structure(list(Col1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Group1", 
"Group2", "Group3"), class = "factor"), Col2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Sp1.1", "Sp1.2", "Sp1.3", 
"Sp1.4", "Sp10.1", "SP11.2", "SP12.1", "Sp2.1", "Sp3.1", "Sp4.1", 
"Sp4.2", "Sp5.1", "Sp6.1", "Sp7.1", "Sp8.1", "Sp8.2", "Sp9.1", 
"Sp9.2", "Sp9.3"), class = "factor"), Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Colvalue1 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12), Colvalue2 = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Mean_dNdS = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f8afd8052e0>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this approach:

- `separate` the `Species` column into 2, since using "Sp" and number to identify `Species`
- `group_by` both `Col1` (the group) and `Species` to look at minimum values of `Colvalue1` within each group/species combination
- Keep just the minimum of `Colvalue1` (and keep `NA` as well since desired in final result)
- Final `pivot_wider` will spread out Groups 1 and 2 in results
- Sort by the numeric value within the `Species` character string

**Edit**: To address Group3 in the example, add an additional `mutate` where if all of the `Colvalue1` are > 5 then substitute with "NO". Code and output have been updated.

**Edit**: To ensure `X` remains after checking `Colvalue1` for levels that are > 5, it also checks to be sure `Colvalue1` is not `NA`. (If it is `NA` then else would make sure `Colvalue2` remains). The mutate statement was edited and output updated below.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate(Col2, into = c("Species", "Species_row"), sep = "([.])") %>%
  group_by(Col1, Species) %>%
  filter(Colvalue1 == min(Colvalue1) | is.na(Colvalue1)) %>%
  mutate(Colvalue2 = replace_na(Colvalue2, "X"),
         Colvalue2 = ifelse(all(Colvalue1 > 5) && all(!is.na(Colvalue1)), "NO", Colvalue2)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_col = Species, names_from = Col1, values_from = Colvalue2) %>%
  arrange(as.integer(str_extract(Species, "\\d+")))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Species [12]
   Species Group1 Group2 Group3
   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
 1 Sp1     A      NA     G     
 2 Sp2     B      NA     NO    
 3 Sp3     B      NA     NO    
 4 Sp4     B      NA     G     
 5 Sp5     B      NA     NA    
 6 Sp6     C      D      NA    
 7 Sp7     NA     D      NA    
 8 Sp8     NA     E      G     
 9 Sp9     NA     E      NA    
10 Sp10    NA     X      NA    
11 SP11    NA     X      NA    
12 SP12    NA     X      NA
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much @Ben !! I bother you just once again to add one little complexity, I illustrate it with the group 3 added in the post, I explain the rules at the end. The idea is to introduce threshold and if thise one is reached and that we do not have any other Event where the Species has a lowest value under this th I put a NO value.

Comment: I get Erreur : Column `Colvalue2` can't be converted from integer to character

Comment: Yes it was that but it seems to work, but the X are not longer present for ```Sp10,11 and 12``` in ```Group2```? I added the dput at the end.

Comment: Okay thank you very much it workes like a charm now !! Take care :)

Comment: @Grendel I  made a minor edit, not sure this would make a difference. But really should be checking if all values are not `NA`. Just edited the mutate. Same answer as far as I can tell.